# Combine 2 columns in a csv file through cmd

Tags: csv, cmd, concatenation

I have a csv file. I want to combine the first two columns through command line in windows. How do I do this?

Comment: Use bash for windows.

Comment: Why not use a utility or make a python code, that would cost no more than 10 lines

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do this. If it isn't possible through cmd line, then it is what is.

Comment: @JerinThenayan Why not open the csv in excel and cascade first two columns, in case you are on windows and it is just one file

Comment: it will be multiple files for a repeated process every week. I already have a batch file running other commands (transferring the file, changing the file name, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy to do with a `FOR` loop. Here is example data.

```
C:>type combi.txt
now,is,the
time,for,all
good,men,to
come,to,the
aid,of,their
```

And here is some code that concatenates the first two (2) fields.

```
C:>type combi.bat
@ECHO OFF

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a IN (`TYPE "combi.txt"`) DO (
    ECHO %%~a%%~b
)
```

And it produces:

```
C:>combi.bat
nowis
timefor
goodmen
cometo
aidof
```

You will need to make the filename a parameter and specify any directory path needed.

Comment: use `tokens=1,*` to combine the first two colums without affecting the rest.

Comment: Just to add, there is no batch-file tag here, the request was for command line with a cmd tag.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a comma delimited format:

```dos
(FOR /F "USEBACKQ TOKENS=1-2* DELIMS=," %A IN ("C:\User Jerin\File.csv") DO @ECHO=%A %B,%C)>"C:\User Jerin\NewFile.csv"
```

I assumed column one was a First Name and column two was a Surname so I included a space between `%A` and `%B`, remove it if not required. Also we have no idea if your `.csv` is quoted fields; if so try using `@ECHO="%~A %~B",%C` instead.